# How can I simulate alignas(T)?

Tags: c++, memory, alignment, memory-alignment

I have an array which is used as the underlying memory of an object of type `T`:

```
char memory[sizeof T];
.
.
.
new(memory) T(whatever);
```

How can I make sure `memory` is aligned correctly for `T` objects? In C++0x I could just say:

```
alignas(T) char memory[sizeof T];
```

but Visual Studio 2010 does not support that particular feature yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual (portable) solution is to put the memory declaration in a union with whatever built-in type in `T` requires the most alignment.
The simplest way would be to use a union with all of the likely
candidates:

```
union MaxAlign
{
    int                 i     ;
    long                l     ;
    long long           ll    ;
    long double         ld    ;
    double              d     ;
    void*               p     ;
    void (*             pf)() ;
    MaxAlign*           ps    ;
} ;

union
{
    MaxAlign dummyForAlignment;
    unsigned char memory[sizeof(T)];
} rawT;
```

I've yet to hear about, much less encounter, a machine where the above
didn't suffice.  Generally, just `double` suffices.  (It is definitely
sufficient on Intel and on Sparc.)

In some extreme cases, this can result in allocating more memory than
necessary, e.g. if `T` only contains one or two `char`.  Most of the
time, this really doesn't matter, and isn't worth worrying about, but if
it is, the following can be used:

```
namespace MyPrivate {

template< typename T, bool isSmaller >
struct AlignTypeDetail ;

template< typename T >
struct AlignTypeDetail< T, false >
{
    typedef T type ;
} ;

template< typename T >
struct AlignTypeDetail< T, true >
{
    typedef char type ;
} ;

template< typename T, typename U >
struct AlignType
{
    typedef typename AlignTypeDetail< U, (sizeof( T ) < sizeof( U )) >::type
                        type ;
} ;
}

template< typename T >
union MaxAlignFor
{
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, char >::type        c ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, short >::type       s ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, int >::type         i ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, long >::type        l ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, long long >::type   ll ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, float >::type       f ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, double >::type      d ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, long double >::type ld ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, void* >::type       pc ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, MaxAlign* >::type   ps ;
    typename MyPrivate::AlignType< T, void (*)() >::type  pf ;
} ;
```

In this case, `MaxAlignFor<T>` will never be bigger than `T`
(and to have sufficient alignment, since the required alignment will
never be larger than the size of `T`).

Note that none of this is formally guaranteed by the standard.  But it
will work in practice.

Comment: @Mehrdad It says that VC++ doesn't support a certain feature.  It doesn't say that this was the only compiler used.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sorry, I commented under the wrong post. See my post below.

Answer (score 5):

Googling for `vc++ align` shows [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx): use `__declspec(align(#))`.

Comment: Which, as the leading `__` distinctly indicate, is a compiler specific extension.

Comment: @JamesKanze: this is 3 years late, but I'll mention it anyway... it does say Visual C++ in the question :)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sorry, I actually commented with my phone and I didn't realize I'm commenting on the wrong post. My reply under your post was meant to be here, in reply to your comment here.

Answer (score 3):

If T is a standard-layout and union is well formed, then

```
union
{
   T t;
   char memory[sizeof T];
};
```

should be aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Either allocate the memory on the heap (which has the alignment guarantee) or use `boost::aligned_storage`.