# C(++) struct force extra padding

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, memory-alignment

I've seen countless questions of the form "I don't like padding how do I turn it off", but have yet to find anything about forcing the compiler to provide extra padding.

The specific case that I have looks like

```
struct particle{
  vect2 s;
  vect2 v;
  int rX;
  int rY;
  double mass;
  int boxNum;
};
```

Where `vect2` is a simple `struct {double x; double y;} vect2`.  In order to use SSE2, I need to be able to load a pair of doubles, aligned to 16 byte boundaries.  This used to work, until I added the extra `int`, pushing my struct size from 48 bytes to 56 bytes.  The result is segfaults.

Is there some kind of compiler directive I can use that either says "pad this struct to make it a multiple of 16 bytes long", or "this struct has an alignment of 16-bytes"?  I know I could do it manually (tacking on an extra char[12], for example), but I'd really rather just tell the compiler(GCC, preferably ICC compatible), and not have to do it manually if I change the struct in future.

Comment: In C++11 there is now [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) for this purpose.

Comment: I don't think GCC has implemented this yet, though.

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959261/how-can-i-simulate-alignast

Comment: Could you union your `vect2` with `__m128`? That should instruct gcc to align your struct to 16 bytes on the stack.

Comment: I actually had it as a union with the __m128d, though I removed it for reasons of being told it was a terrible idea in terms of the resulting generated code, and that _mm_load_pd() should be used instead.  Just using that for alignment could work though.

Comment: Another option to force padding is to add unnamed bitfields to the struct. `struct particle { vect2 s; ...; double mass; unsigned long : 32; unsigned long : 32; int boxNum; };` (in C, you can portably use one bitfield `unsigned long long : 64;` for the padding, not sure whether C++ has a portable integer type with >= 64 bits now).

Comment: @Daniel : C++11 officially has `long long` now, but most compilers supported it as a C++03 extension anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding my own answer to this, in case someone comes looking for a solution.  Mark's solution is a neat one, and fulfills the automatic requirement, but it is not when I ended up going with.  I wanted to avoid this, which is why I asked the question, but there is a "trivial" solution:

```
struct particle{
  vect2 s;
  vect2 v;
  int rX;
  int rY;
  double mass;
  int boxNum;
  char padding[12];
};
```

By manually checking the current size of the `struct`, you can add an appropriate number of chars, (or anything else, but `char`'s let you do it in bytes), to make it the right size.  This showed the best performance, as well as simplicity, even though it does require updating every time the struct changes.  In this case that is fine, although if you had a struct that could change size depending on options, that would be problematic.

Note that my `struct` was 56 bytes, and I added 12 to make it 64.  That math doesn't work, because the trailing `int` was already being padded out by 4 bytes to the 8-byte boundary; the `struct` was actually only 52 bytes before.  Adding only 5 `char`s would have worked, by making the `struct` 57 bytes long, which would have been padded out to 64, but that is not as nice a solution, which is why I used 12 to make it work out exactly.

Comment: That seems sensible given the performance requirements; for the sake of your coworkers and future maintainers (including your future self) *please* comment the fix and add a compile time assert that the `struct` is a multiple of 16 bytes in size.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you didn't want to leave this to the compiler, e.g. with `__attribute__((aligned(16)))`?

Answer (score 9):

You can nest two structures to pad it automatically without needing to keep track of the size yourself.

```
struct particle
{
    // ...
};

{
    particle p;
    char padding[16-(sizeof(particle)%16)];
};
```

This version unfortunately adds 16 bytes if the structure is already a multiple of 16. It's unavoidable because the standard doesn't allow arrays of zero length.

Some compilers do allow zero length arrays as an extension, and in that case you can do this instead:

```
struct particle_wrapper
{
    particle p;
    char padding[sizeof(particle)%16 ? 16-(sizeof(particle)%16) : 0];
};
```

This version does not add any bytes of padding if the structure is already a multiple of 16.

Comment: You can avoid adding 16 bytes by doing `char padding[ (sizeof(particle) + 15) & ~15 ]`.

Comment: It is, but only works because 16 is a power of 2. It's easier to understand if you consider that `~15` is `1..10000` in binary, i.e. it filters out the last four bits, leaving a multiple of 16. Since this just truncates the number to a multiple of 16, we have to add 15 first so that we get the next-highest multiple.

Comment: @Pedro, consider if `sizeof(particle) == 1` - your padding will be 16 bytes, leading to a total size of 17 bytes. I think you meant `15` instead of `~15`, but even that's not right because it would add only 1 byte instead of 15. `%16` and `&15` are identical operations. You need to add the inverse of the size of the struct, which is what I did with `16-...`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to subtract the actual size of the `struct`. The correct declaration is `char padding[ ((sizeof(particle) + 15) & ~15) - sizeof(particle)]`. In any case, this is all moot since, in `gcc`, adding `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` at the end of the struct declaration does this automatically.

Comment: @Pedro, with that correction you and I finally agree. The only problem now is when the size is already a multiple of 16 and you're trying to create `padding[0]`, even if the compiler allows it it might reserve an extra byte.

Comment: Unfortunately, `padding[0]` is not legal; arrays must have at least one element.

Comment: @ecatmur: A padding of size zero is [legal in `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) and should have size zero bytes. Again, though, this is all a massive hack that can be avoided by using `__attribute__((aligned(16)))`.

Comment: Hmm, can't you nest in a union to work around the already-aligned problem? `union { struct particle p; char alignment[sizeof(struct particle) - (sizeof(struct particle) % 16) + 16]; }`

Answer (score 9):

In `gcc`, you can align arbitrary types and variables with [`__attribute__((aligned(...)))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html). For your example, this would be

```
struct particle{
  vect2 s;
  vect2 v;
  int rX;
  int rY;
  double mass;
  int boxNum;
} __attribute__((aligned (16)));
```

This automagically padds the struct so that arrays thereof will be correctly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The new C++11 spec also has a [new feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) for this, though I do not believe many vendors have been implemented them yet.

<strike>You can try the pack pragma, though it is not supported by the spec.  Both GCC and MS support it though.</strike>

This aligns the struct on 1 byte boundaries, though you can change the number to anything you want.

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
// ...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

update:

So apparently the above will not work as it only shrinks padding, never expanding it.  Regretfully, I don't have a testing environment this afternoon.

Maybe using an anonymous union would work.  I know it will expand to the largest size, though I don't know if you get any guarantees about alignment otherwise.

```
template<typename T, size_t padding_size>
  struct padded_field {
    union {
      T value;
      uint8_t padding[padding_size];
    };
  };
```

Comment: I tried that; when set to 4, it squishes down to 52 bytes.. but when set to 16, it stays at 56, so I assumed that it doesn't expand the padding, only force tighter packing.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with gcc's implementation, but per [the Visual C++ documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx), "The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, **whichever is smaller**."

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this might work:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

struct particle{
  union {
    vect2 s;
    __m128 s_for_alignment;
  };
  union {
    vect2 v;
    __m128 v_for_alignment;
  };
  ...
};
```

I know that gcc had issues aligning `__m128` correctly previously, but those should be fixed by now.

Comment: In that case I might as well go with `union vect2 { __m128d s; struct{ double x; double y;};};`, but yes, that might be the way to go.

Comment: Testing indicates that this works about 10% slower than manually padding; I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Crazy.  Any differences in the generated asm?

Comment: Reading ASM isn't my strong suit, but when I turn on the union (also padded the struct so that I was only benchmarking one change, the number of instructions recorded by Callgrind went from 11G to 13G.  Comparing one of the slow sections, I notice 20 instead of 10 instructions in the loop: It goes from `movsd{3}, addsd{2}, movsd{2}, ucomisd, jbe` to `mov, movsd, mov{8}, addsd, mov{3}, movsd, addsd, movsd, ucomisd, movsdjbe`.  Most of the movs appear to be shuffling things around with `%rdx`, `%rax`, and `0x??(%rsp)`.

Comment: @zebediah49 to me that reads like code wasn't properly optimized. I know this was forever ago but do you remember if you were passing strong-enough optimization flags to GCC (such as `-O3` or at least `-O2`)? I imagine a recent compiler version given freedom to optimize wouldn't have inefficiencies that severe.